# JQuery hide/slideToggle elem in scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and looking for a solution, how to add a list of `ul id = "animalsListDetails"`, hide / show on the HTML page and rendering this scope, when click a-ref:

```
function renderAnimalsList(data) {
    var list = data == null ? [] : (data instanceof Array ? data : [data]);

    $('#animalsList li').hide();
    $('#animalsListDetails li').hide();
    $.each(list, function (index, animals){ 

        $('.animals').click(function () {
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    }).append('<ul id="animalsList"><li><a href="#"> Animal Id: ' + animals.id + '</a><br> <ul id="animalsListDetails"><li> Name: '+ animals.animalname + '<br> Birthday: ' + animals.dateborn + '<br> Sex: ' + animals.sex + '<br> Type animal: ' + animals.typesanimalsId + '</li></ul></li></ul>');
});
```

}

call function:

```
function findAnimalByCustomerId(customerId){
    console.log('findAnimalByCustomerId: ' + customerId);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: customerlistURL + '/' + customerId + '/myanimals',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('findAnimalByCustomerId success: ' + customerId);
            renderAnimalsList(data);
        }
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="animals">


    </div>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML and where you're calling `renderAnimalsList`

Comment: I added to the question

Comment: $.each(list, function (index, animals)  is missing { after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
(function($, undefined){
 $(function(){
 $(document).ready(function(){


//bind handlers
function domHandlers() {
    $('.animal-id').click(function(e){
        slideToggle(e);
    });
}


function renderAnimalsList(jsonData) {
    var list = jsonData;

    $.each(list, function (i, animal) {
        $('#animalsList').append('<li><a href="#!" class="animal-id"> Animal Id: '   + animal.id + '</a></li>');

        //With details:
        $('#animalsList').append('<li class="animal-details hidden">' +
            'Name: ' + animal.animalname + '<br>' +
            'Birthday: ' + animal.dateborn + '<br>' +
            ' Sex: ' + animal.sex + '<br>' +
            ' Type animal: ' + animal.typesanimalsId + '</li>');
    });
}


function slideToggle(e) {

    $('.animal-details ').addClass('hidden');
    $(e.target).closest('li').next().removeClass('hidden');

}


renderAnimalsList(jsonData);

domHandlers();
   });
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If the main motive of question is to know how to add the list, following answer shows that with mocked data. If you wanna know more, please ask in comments (try to define your problem at once).

```js
function renderAnimalsList(data) {
  var list = data == null ? [] : (data instanceof Array ? data : [data]);

  $('#animalsList li').hide();
  $('#animalsListDetails li').hide();
  $.each(list, function(index, animals) {

    $('.animals').click(function() {
      console.log(this);
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
    }).append('<ul id="animalsList"><li><a href="#"> Animal Id: ' + animals.id + '</a></li>');
    //whith details
    $('#animalsList').append('<ul id="animalsListDetails"><li>Name: ' + animals.animalname + '<br> Birthday: ' + animals.dateborn + '<br> Sex: ' + animals.sex + '<br> Type animal: ' + animals.typesanimalsId + '</li></ul>');
  });
}

var animals = [{
  animalname: 'Tiger',
  dateborn: '----.--.--',
  sex: 'M',
  typesanimalsId: 1,
  id: 10
}, {
  animalname: 'Tiger 2',
  dateborn: '----.--.--',
  sex: 'M',
  typesanimalsId: 1,
  id: 11
}, {
  animalname: 'Tiger 3',
  dateborn: '----.--.--',
  sex: 'M',
  typesanimalsId: 1,
  id: 12
}]

function findAnimalByCustomerId(customerId) {
  // This function is useless in this context
  console.log('findAnimalByCustomerId: ' + customerId);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: customerlistURL + '/' + customerId + '/myanimals',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('findAnimalByCustomerId success: ' + customerId);
      renderAnimalsList(data);
    }
  });
}

//This ready function will be calling renderAnimalsList in same way as it will be called in above findAnimalByCustomerId
$(document).ready(function() {
  renderAnimalsList(animals);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animals">
  <div id="animalsList"></div>
  <div id="animalsListDetails"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank's, I asked an incorrect question, so sorry. It's a response from a server in json-format. The entity id needs to be make reference, and the details are hidden/show. That's all.